# How to center an image in the middle of a div?

Tags: html, css, position, vertical-alignment

I need to center an image in a middle of a div.

```
<div class="main">
    <img...>
</div>
```

In the example below the image is centered, but not in the middle.

https://jsfiddle.net/web_garaux/tng7db0k/

Comment: There are so many different ways to do this if you just googled

Comment: Please read this: [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - the very top line: search and research... a simple search of this site would reveal hundreds of similar questions.  Please put in a little effort before asking a question next time

Comment: Holy Hell, this is like the most asked and answered question on this site.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Simple and easy method to do this,

```css
.test {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 700px;
  height: 700px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

To vertically center your div, you can use [positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position). Just apply

```
position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

to your image, and it will be vertically centered.

```css
.test {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 700px;
  height: 700px;
  text-align: center;
}

.test>img {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the simplest way -> display: table-cell; which allows you to use vertical-align attribute

```css
.test {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: flex;`

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tng7db0k/2/)

```
.test {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 700px;
  height: 700px;
}

.test img {
  align-self: center;
}
```

Comment: Why not use `align-items` on the flex container

Comment: @Huangism no specific reason I guess just showing it can be done like this as well.

Comment: works only on Chrome.

Comment: @EnexoOnoma this is battle tested so it works (with browser support for flex). There has to be something else that is off with your code. Do a post of your issue, you can ping me on it and I could have a look if you like :)

Answer (score 0):

Cleanest solution would be to make your div `display:flex` and align/justify content to center.

```
.test {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 700px;
  height: 700px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Your updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y9j21ocr/1/

[More reads on flexbox (recommended)](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: works only on Chrome.

Comment: Really? The posted fiddle works fine on MS Edge (RIP) and Firefox. Curious to hear more info! :)

Answer (score 0):

It is really easy if you can give image as background to div

```
.test {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 700px;
  height: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}

<div class="test" style="background-image:url(http://via.placeholder.com/350x150);">
</div>
```

If you dont want to use inline style you can do

```
<div class="test">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
</div>

.test > img{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
.test{position: relative}
```

Comment: Please don't do this as your mixing up content with layout.

Comment: its an easy practice and it was used before flexbox or any other method was here. and believe me if you get image link somehow there is not a different loading it on style or in html. If you really hesitated to see a completely seperate layout I updated my answer you can check it.

Comment: The absolute positioning + transform is a better approach than adding the image as background. Flexbox is also an option but not always the best one. Just avoid mixing content with layout.